# NESTJS - un modulo afecta modulos externos que no cuentan con relacion hacia el mismos

Tags: backend, nestjs

Estoy implementando guards personalizados para la autenticacion de las rutas, se me presento un problema poco inusual, tengo 3 modulos:

-Role

-Auth

-User

Agrego la autenticacion en User, y todo funciona y dichas rutas quedan protegidas, cuando las implemento en el modulo de roles, me crea un error entre el modulo User y Auth...

> ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (JwtService, ?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1] is available in the AuthModule context.

No entiendo porque el modulo Role que no tiene relacion con User, esta creando un error a un modulo externo a el.

Dejo el flujo que estoy creando

RoleController

```html
@Swagger(200, 'Role', 'RoleList', RestApiRequest.get)
  @PermissionsProtected(PermissionsValid.Get)
  @Auth(ModulesValid.role)
  findAll() {
    return this.roleService.findAll();
  }
```

RoleModule

```html
@Module({
  controllers: [RolesController],
  providers: [RolesService],
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Role, RolePermission, RoleModulePermissions]),
    AuthModule,
  ],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule, RolesService],
})
export class RolesModule {}
```

AuthService:

```html
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
    private readonly userService: UserService
  ) {}
  }
```

AuthModule:

```html
@Module({
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          secret: configService.get<string>('SECRETKEY'),
          signOptions: {
            expiresIn: '30m',
          },
        };
      },
    }),
    forwardRef(() => UserModule),
  ],
  exports: [JwtStrategy, PassportModule, JwtModule],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

UserModule

```html
@Module({
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, Role]),
    forwardRef(() => AuthModule),
    SendEmailModule,
  ],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule, UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Alguien podria apoyarme a darme una perspectiva diferente, gracias!!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahí Nest te está indicando que estás teniendo conflictos con la inyección de dependencias del userService que se encuentra en el método constructor del AuthService.
Hay que hacer una inyección con el decorador Inject.

```
 export class AuthService {
   constructor(
     private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
     @Inject(forwardRef(() => UserService))
     private readonly userService: UserService
   ) {}
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero crei que solo con hacer el referencia circular en el modulo, no ocasionaria problemas, entonces en estos casos, se debe inyectar la referencia directamente en el constructor?

Por que razon se ocasionan esos errores?, quisiera saber si no es mucha molestia, gracias :3

Comment: Hola ! Si no colocas el decorador inject en tu constructor, Nest no los instanciará porque todos los metadatos esenciales no estarán disponibles. Así que es necesario usarlo.

Comment: La referencia que agregaste en tus módulos, es para decirle que los providers que vayas a utilizar, vienen de un modulo externo, más NO lo van a instanciar los servicios que vayas a usar. Es por eso que te sale el problema de que Nest no puede encontrar la dependencia del userService.